# Ag-grid-react with react testing library throws render error

Tags: ag-grid, react-testing-library, ag-grid-react

Tyring to unit test ag-grid-react with react testing library but unfortunately, I tend to be getting the same error over and over despite numerous attempts changing the how the component is rendered in the test.

When the tests are run, this error is thrown every time:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: this.eIconWrapper.insertAdjacentElement is not a function]
```

The ag-grid-react version is at 25.1.0

I have also attempted this walkthrough: https://github.com/ag-grid/react-data-grid/blob/main/podcast-player/v8/src/PodcastGrid.test.js by waiting for the grid to be in the dom but still the errors persist:

```
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19527
The above error occurred in the <AgGridReact> component:
    in AgGridReact (at grid/index.jsx:229)
```

Further down the error seems to be pointing towards some sidebar component:

```
TypeError: this.eIconWrapper.insertAdjacentElement is not a function

at SideBarButtonComp.Object.<anonymous>.SideBarButtonComp.postConstruct
```